# Synchronization stopped working: Microsoft Exchange contacts with Nexus 4

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, android, exchange, contacts

I have in my office Microsoft Exchange 2010 on Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2. My Nexus 4 (Android 4.4.2) is configured to sync contacts (only) with it. It used to work and then stopped (although no sign of error message - according to the Nexus all is fine). I deleted the account and added it again and it synced well for a few days and then again, nothing.

The Exchange sees the sync attempts and below you can see the log it creates, claiming sync went well (but it didn't of course).

```
-----------------
 Log Entry: 0
-----------------

RequestTime : 
02/21/2014 19:17:25

ServerName : 
(censored)

AssemblyVersion : 
14.01.0438.000

Identifier : 
2CDB6312

RequestHeader : 
POST /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync/default.eas?Cmd=Sync&User=(censored)&DeviceId=androidc136555749&DeviceType=Android HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 156
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-sync.wbxml
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: ********
Host: (censored)
User-Agent: Android/4.4.2-EAS-1.3
MS-ASProtocolVersion: 14.1
X-MS-PolicyKey: 4026086125


RequestBody : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <SyncKey>910113764</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>14</CollectionId>
            <DeletesAsMoves/>
            <GetChanges/>
            <WindowSize>10</WindowSize>
            <Options>
                <BodyPreference xmlns="AirSyncBase:">
                    <Type>1</Type>
                    <TruncationSize>200000</TruncationSize>
                </BodyPreference>
            </Options>
            <Commands>
                <Add>
                    <ClientId>new_1587_1393002883923</ClientId>
                    <ApplicationData>
                        <MobilePhoneNumber xmlns="Contacts:" bytes="10"/>
                    </ApplicationData>
                </Add>
                <Add>
                    <ClientId>new_1587_1393002884091</ClientId>
                    <ApplicationData>
                        <MobilePhoneNumber xmlns="Contacts:" bytes="10"/>
                    </ApplicationData>
                </Add>
            </Commands>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>

LogicalRequest : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <SyncKey>910113764</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>14</CollectionId>
            <DeletesAsMoves/>
            <GetChanges/>
            <WindowSize>10</WindowSize>
            <Options>
                <BodyPreference xmlns="AirSyncBase:">
                    <Type>1</Type>
                    <TruncationSize>200000</TruncationSize>
                </BodyPreference>
            </Options>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>

AccessState : 
Allowed

AccessStateReason : 
Global

ResponseHeader : 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
MS-Server-ActiveSync: 14.1


ResponseBody : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:">
    <Status>12</Status>
</Sync>

ResponseTime : 
02/21/2014 19:17:25


-----------------
 Log Entry: 1
-----------------

RequestTime : 
02/21/2014 19:17:27

ServerName : 
(censored)

AssemblyVersion : 
14.01.0438.000

Identifier : 
7F8DFA2E

RequestHeader : 
POST /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync/default.eas?Cmd=Sync&User=(censored)&DeviceId=androidc136555749&DeviceType=Android HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 156
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-sync.wbxml
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: ********
Host: (censored)
User-Agent: Android/4.4.2-EAS-1.3
MS-ASProtocolVersion: 14.1
X-MS-PolicyKey: 4026086125


RequestBody : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <SyncKey>961414273</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>37</CollectionId>
            <DeletesAsMoves/>
            <GetChanges/>
            <WindowSize>10</WindowSize>
            <Options>
                <BodyPreference xmlns="AirSyncBase:">
                    <Type>1</Type>
                    <TruncationSize>200000</TruncationSize>
                </BodyPreference>
            </Options>
            <Commands>
                <Add>
                    <ClientId>new_1606_1393002887385</ClientId>
                    <ApplicationData>
                        <MobilePhoneNumber xmlns="Contacts:" bytes="10"/>
                    </ApplicationData>
                </Add>
                <Add>
                    <ClientId>new_1606_1393002887447</ClientId>
                    <ApplicationData>
                        <MobilePhoneNumber xmlns="Contacts:" bytes="10"/>
                    </ApplicationData>
                </Add>
            </Commands>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>

LogicalRequest : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <SyncKey>961414273</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>37</CollectionId>
            <DeletesAsMoves/>
            <GetChanges/>
            <WindowSize>10</WindowSize>
            <Options>
                <BodyPreference xmlns="AirSyncBase:">
                    <Type>1</Type>
                    <TruncationSize>200000</TruncationSize>
                </BodyPreference>
            </Options>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>

AccessState : 
Allowed

AccessStateReason : 
Global

ResponseHeader : 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
MS-Server-ActiveSync: 14.1


ResponseBody : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:">
    <Status>12</Status>
</Sync>

ResponseTime : 
02/21/2014 19:17:27


-----------------
 Log Entry: 2
-----------------

RequestTime : 
02/21/2014 19:17:28

ServerName : 
(censored)

AssemblyVersion : 
14.01.0438.000

Identifier : 
18CB5931

RequestHeader : 
POST /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync/default.eas?Cmd=Sync&User=(censored)&DeviceId=androidc136555749&DeviceType=Android HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 156
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-sync.wbxml
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: ********
Host: (censored)
User-Agent: Android/4.4.2-EAS-1.3
MS-ASProtocolVersion: 14.1
X-MS-PolicyKey: 4026086125


RequestBody : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <SyncKey>645226313</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>44</CollectionId>
            <DeletesAsMoves/>
            <GetChanges/>
            <WindowSize>10</WindowSize>
            <Options>
                <BodyPreference xmlns="AirSyncBase:">
                    <Type>1</Type>
                    <TruncationSize>200000</TruncationSize>
                </BodyPreference>
            </Options>
            <Commands>
                <Add>
                    <ClientId>new_1612_1393002888458</ClientId>
                    <ApplicationData>
                        <MobilePhoneNumber xmlns="Contacts:" bytes="10"/>
                    </ApplicationData>
                </Add>
                <Add>
                    <ClientId>new_1612_1393002888505</ClientId>
                    <ApplicationData>
                        <MobilePhoneNumber xmlns="Contacts:" bytes="10"/>
                    </ApplicationData>
                </Add>
            </Commands>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>

LogicalRequest : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <SyncKey>645226313</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>44</CollectionId>
            <DeletesAsMoves/>
            <GetChanges/>
            <WindowSize>10</WindowSize>
            <Options>
                <BodyPreference xmlns="AirSyncBase:">
                    <Type>1</Type>
                    <TruncationSize>200000</TruncationSize>
                </BodyPreference>
            </Options>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>

AccessState : 
Allowed

AccessStateReason : 
Global

ResponseHeader : 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
MS-Server-ActiveSync: 14.1


ResponseBody : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:">
    <Status>12</Status>
</Sync>

ResponseTime : 
02/21/2014 19:17:28
```